# ReSharper TypeScript seems to be not working at all in my VS 2015 installation

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, resharper

ReSharper TypeScript seems to be not working at all in my VS 2015 installation. Despite of the correctly placed TypeScript definitions ReSharper does not recognize the defined types, gives zillion red underlines, and of course intellisense does not work on the variables.

The error message is for example: `Could not find symbol 'JQuery'`

Some more diagnostics:

- Compiling the project in VS 2015 compiles with no error. Making an intentional error in the source then build generates one correct error message
- Intentionally making a spell in the type definition file paths, it underlined with red correctly. When correcting the path, underline diasppears
- Opening the very same project in VS 2013 all works like a charm, ReSharper is working correctly
- Originally used ReSharper 9.1.2 this issue was there. Now upgraded to the latest 9.1.3 and the issue remained.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you try cleaning the caches? ReSharper &rarr; Options &rarr; General &rarr; Clean Caches, then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Thx, yes, it worked. Please drop a line as answer.

Comment: Same problem with ReSharper 2017.3.3 in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.3. The TypeScript compiles and runs just fine. Wiping the R# caches and restarting VS doesn't help. It's sad. Not only has ReSharper become unbelievably slow over the years (what is it doing?), now it is getting in the way of working with code by highlighting bogus errors. Usually I don't use ReSharper any more. Instead I use Roslynator for refactoring and NUnit for testing. Officially you can switch ReSharper support for TS off in options.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you see this kind of behaviour - lots of red, but clean compile, especially after an upgrade - you should try to clean the caches. Go to ReSharper → Options → General → Clean caches, then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: For me , Resharper didn't intellisense typescript at all. I had to do this : https://i.imgur.com/vrvN0mb.jpg in order to see some intellisense . But now , I can't enjoy the resharper's intellisense in TS. :-(

Comment: Works for VS 2017 as well. Lifesaver, than you.

Comment: Thank you! This happened to me after updating to version 2020.2.  You'd think that JetBrains might have thought to clear the cache during the upgrade, but clearly not. Just goes to show that seemingly ancient SO posts can still be relevant after several years.

Answer (score 4):

Since the problem occurs in more than one version including latest as of writing, you also have the option to switch off TypeScript support in ReSharper. After all, if a feature is broken, why use it?

How to switch it off according to their web site:

> If necessary, you can disable/enable ReSharper features in TypeScript
>   files by clearing the corresponding check box on the Environment |
>   Products & Feature page of ReSharper options.

Source: [JetBrains help page for ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_by_Language__TypeScript.html) (retrieved 29 March 2018)

After this change you may have to restart Visual Studio for the new settings to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that sometimes, the Visual Studio Project file is corrupted, containing multiple references to `.ts` files. This can cause a different, but related error, where ReSharper thinks there are multiple declarations of a symbol.

To resolve, if you are using version control, it is simple.

- Make a commit
- Delete the folder containing the duplicated files
- Revert changes to the repository
- Add the folder back to Visual Studio
- Save the project file

As I mentioned, this doesn't solve the original problem, but can help in situations where ReSharper reports duplicate symbols.